# Can't fetch whole the header element via net/http call

Tags: go, http-headers

I want to get a header element called Set-Cookie which is in the response of an authentication service.

I make an http call to get data from a remote server:

```
resp, err := client.Do(httpRequest)
```

Once I login, the response is as below:

```
fmt.Println(resp.Header)
// the result is:
// map[Cache-Control:[private] Content-Length:[0] Content-Security-Policy:[frame-ancestors 'self'] Date:[Tue, 01 Sep 2020 06:44:02 GMT] Expires:[0] Pragma:[no-cache] Set-Cookie:[sg-dummy=-; path=/; HttpOnly sg-auth-XXXX=4a49891d-2c46-4f50-a516-68a2e337f2a7; path=/; HttpOnly] X-Frame-Options:[SAMEORIGIN] X-Xss-Protection:[1; mode=block]]
```

I want this element:

```
Set-Cookie:[sg-dummy=-; path=/; HttpOnly sg-auth-XXXX=4a49891d-2c46-4f50-a516-68a2e337f2a7; path=/; HttpOnly]
```

However, once I get that part I see a redacted version of Set-Cookie string:

```
fmt.Println(resp.Header.Get("Set-Cookie")
// I get this part only:
// sg-dummy=-; path=/; HttpOnly
```

How should I get the whole stuff?

Comment: As usual: Start by reading the documentation of net/http.Header to what type it is. From that it is obvious how to get what you want. Go is really different here to other languages: Read the documentation and understand the types involved. In Go this is doable, easy, quick and helpful.

Comment: I got this. Yes you are right! Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be multiple cookies. `Header.Get` will only return the first element if the header has multiple elements. Access it as a map:

```
for _,cookie:=range resp.Header["Set-Cookie"] {
   // This should iterate twice
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Headers can have multiple values associated with a given key. This is the case in your example.

[Header.Get](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Get) returns only the first value associated with a given key:

> Get gets the first value associated with the given key. If there are no values associated with the key, Get returns "".

Instead, you need to use [Header.Values](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Header.Values) which returns all of them:

> Values returns all values associated with the given key.

```golang
fmt.Println(resp.Header.Values("Set-Cookie"))
```

I recommend reading the documentation for the functions you use.